# Is there any simple way of taking integer inputs from user to fill up a vector and also provide an option to stop in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, std, cin

I need a block of code that takes input from user as long as he wishes and fill up a vector with it. I got stuck at providing some stop mechanism by which user can inform the end of inputs. I tried to input a 'char' but in that case cin doesn't work further and sometimes leads to an infinite loop. And also I don't want to block any integer input.

I wonder if there is any way except taking input to a string and then converting.

I don't get the idea of parsing very clearly, should I check it?

Here's what I tried:

```
int val;
vector<int> v;
while(cin>>val)
    {
        if(val == '$') break;
        v.push_back(val);
    }
```

Comment: You likely need to provide more code, in the form of a [mcve]. For instance, what is `val`?

Comment: Read a string. Check for ending, else [convert to integer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Comment: You're reading in an integer and then checking if the **integer** that you just read is equal to `'$'`.

Comment: Assuming `val` is an `int`, then `while(cin>>val)` will fail when user enters non-integer. That is fine, but if you want to read more input, you need to clear the error and ignore the char: [Why would we call cin.clear() and cin.ignore() after reading input?](//stackoverflow.com/a/5131654)

Comment: If you make `val` of type `int` then formatted input `std::cin >> val` will fail for input of `$` and leave the loop. Isn't is what you are looking for? (The test `if(val == '$') break;` is needless, of course, but may cause false positives. Check what happens now if you input 36.) ;-)

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyMopp. using cin.clear and cin.ignore solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you @Scheff It worked without the break statement. It's funny. I also forgot that the ASCII values of characters can ruin my dreams of not blocking integer. :-)

Comment: May be you could ask for the number of `vals` beforehand.